Which point is closest to the mean of all points?
I have this graph in R in which each node has a random weight:
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

g <- sample_gnm(n = 20, m = 30, directed = FALSE)
V(g)$weight <- runif(20)

I am trying to find out which node has a weight closest to the mean of all nodes.
If this was not a network graph, it would be pretty easy to do. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this using a network graph object.
I tried to do this using the following way:
tibble(
    node_id = 1:20,
    weight = V(g)$weight,
    mean_weight_of_all_nodes = mean(V(g)$weight),
    abs_distance_from_mean = abs(weight - mean_weight_of_all_nodes)
) %>%
    arrange(abs_distance_from_mean) %>%
    mutate(rank = row_number())

The result looks like this:
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   node_id weight mean_weight_of_all_nodes abs_distance_from_mean  rank
     <int>  <dbl>                    <dbl>                  <dbl> <int>
 1      12 0.414                     0.396                 0.0180     1
 2      11 0.415                     0.396                 0.0188     2
 3      13 0.369                     0.396                 0.0269     3
 4      17 0.466                     0.396                 0.0702     4
 5       8 0.318                     0.396                 0.0776     5
 6       5 0.478                     0.396                 0.0820     6
 7      18 0.266                     0.396                 0.130      7
 8      16 0.233                     0.396                 0.163      8
 9       9 0.232                     0.396                 0.164      9
10       7 0.216                     0.396                 0.179     10
11      14 0.152                     0.396                 0.243     11
12      10 0.143                     0.396                 0.253     12
13      15 0.139                     0.396                 0.257     13
14       2 0.691                     0.396                 0.295     14
15      20 0.0458                    0.396                 0.350     15
16       6 0.758                     0.396                 0.363     16
17       4 0.0246                    0.396                 0.371     17
18       3 0.795                     0.396                 0.400     18
19      19 0.858                     0.396                 0.462     19
20       1 0.902                     0.396                 0.507     20

Is this the correct way to do it?

Your implementation is correct, and it can be simplified to:
library(igraph)

# same graph from the question
set.seed(123)
g <- sample_gnm(n = 20, m = 30, directed = FALSE)
V(g)$weight <- runif(20)

mean_weight <- mean(V(g)$weight)

# find the node with weight closest to the mean
closest_node <- which.min(abs(V(g)$weight - mean_weight))

list(
  "node id" = closest_node,
  "node weight" = V(g)$weight[closest_node],
  "mean weight" = mean_weight
)

> list(
+   "node id" = closest_node,
+   "node weight" = V(g)$weight[closest_node],
+   "mean weight" = mean_weight
+ )
$`node id`
[1] 12

$`node weight`
[1] 0.4137243

$`mean weight`
[1] 0.3957675



If this was not a network graph /.../

You might like tidygraph .

/.../ a tidy API for graph/network manipulation. While network data itself is not tidy, it can be envisioned as two tidy tables, one for node data and one for edge data. /.../

library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)
set.seed(123)

g <- sample_gnm(n = 20, m = 30, directed = FALSE)
V(g)$weight <- runif(20)

g_ranked <- 
  as_tbl_graph(g) |> 
  activate(nodes) |> 
  mutate(
    abs_distance_from_mean = abs(weight - mean(weight)),
    rank = row_number(abs_distance_from_mean)
  )
g_ranked
#> # A tbl_graph: 20 nodes and 30 edges
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 20 × 3 (active)
#>    weight abs_distance_from_mean  rank
#>     <dbl>                  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 0.902                  0.507     20
#>  2 0.691                  0.295     14
#>  3 0.795                  0.400     18
#>  4 0.0246                 0.371     17
#>  5 0.478                  0.0820     6
#>  6 0.758                  0.363     16
#>  7 0.216                  0.179     10
#>  8 0.318                  0.0776     5
#>  9 0.232                  0.164      9
#> 10 0.143                  0.253     12
#> 11 0.415                  0.0188     2
#> 12 0.414                  0.0180     1
#> 13 0.369                  0.0269     3
#> 14 0.152                  0.243     11
#> 15 0.139                  0.257     13
#> 16 0.233                  0.163      8
#> 17 0.466                  0.0702     4
#> 18 0.266                  0.130      7
#> 19 0.858                  0.462     19
#> 20 0.0458                 0.350     15
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 30 × 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     3
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     5
#> # ℹ 27 more rows

g_ranked |> 
  slice_min(rank) |> 
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   weight abs_distance_from_mean  rank
#>    <dbl>                  <dbl> <int>
#> 1  0.414                 0.0180     1

Created on 2024-11-11 with reprex v2.1.1

Another option might be as_data_frame() + within()
library(igraph)
as_data_frame(g, what = "vertices") |>
  within({
    mean_weight = mean(weight) 
    abs_diff = abs(weight - mean_weight)
    }) |> sort_by(~abs_diff)

giving
    weight   abs_diff mean_weight
12 0.41372433 0.01795679   0.3957675
11 0.41454634 0.01877880   0.3957675
13 0.36884545 0.02692208   0.3957675
17 0.46596245 0.07019492   0.3957675
8  0.31818101 0.07758653   0.3957675

Notice that the data frame is sorted. An explicit rank calculation is the alternative. We might want to move the row names to an identifier column.

You can do the same thing as you did before, but just need to generate a dataframe from g
g %>%
  {
    data.frame(node_id = V(.), weight = V(.)$weight)
  } %>%
  mutate(
    mean_weight_of_all_nodes = mean(V(g)$weight),
    abs_distance_from_mean = abs(weight - mean_weight_of_all_nodes)
  ) %>%
  arrange(abs_distance_from_mean) %>%
  mutate(rank = row_number())

which gives
   node_id     weight mean_weight_of_all_nodes abs_distance_from_mean rank
1       12 0.41372433                0.3957675             0.01795679    1
2       11 0.41454634                0.3957675             0.01877880    2
3       13 0.36884545                0.3957675             0.02692208    3
4       17 0.46596245                0.3957675             0.07019492    4
5        8 0.31818101                0.3957675             0.07758653    5
6        5 0.47779597                0.3957675             0.08202844    6
7       18 0.26597264                0.3957675             0.12979489    7
8       16 0.23303410                0.3957675             0.16273343    8
9        9 0.23162579                0.3957675             0.16414175    9
10       7 0.21640794                0.3957675             0.17935960   10
11      14 0.15244475                0.3957675             0.24332279   11
12      10 0.14280002                0.3957675             0.25296751   12
13      15 0.13880606                0.3957675             0.25696147   13
14       2 0.69070528                0.3957675             0.29493774   14
15      20 0.04583117                0.3957675             0.34993637   15
16       6 0.75845954                0.3957675             0.36269200   16
17       4 0.02461368                0.3957675             0.37115385   17
18       3 0.79546742                0.3957675             0.39969988   18
19      19 0.85782772                0.3957675             0.46206018   19
20       1 0.90229905                0.3957675             0.50653151   20

